# Send POST request using API python

Tags: python, api

I am executing below post request and getting error "Premature end of file"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import os, unittest, time, re, random, datetime
import requests


class Sauce(unittest.TestCase):

def test_create_contract(self):
    payload = {'PO_ID': '3557698',' MAN': 'HQF01'}
    r = requests.post(
        "https://time.tps.com/xml/Msg.jsp?msg=MSG_RAM_INFO&user=Dist1&pass=ome1")
    print r
print r.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Where as when I tried with soap client using XML file its working fine
My XML file is

```
<SO>
  <PO_ID>3557698</PO_ID>
  <MAN>HQF01</MAN>
</SO>
```

I need to send a post request and need to get response.

Comment: I recommend using an IDE like PyCharm, which would have given you a warning that the variable `payload` is never used.

Answer (score 0):

```
r=requests.post("https://time.tps.com/xml/Msg.jsp?msg=MSG_RAM_INFO&user=Dist1&pass=ome1")
```

But you're really not sending the post data. You should add data = payload to that post request.

```
url = "https://time.tps.com/xml/Msg.jsp?msg=MSG_RAM_INFO&user=Dist1&pass=ome1"
payload={'PO_ID': '3557698','MAN': 'HQF01'}
r=requests.post(url,data = payload)
```

EDIT :

Try this

```
payload = "<SO><PO_ID>3557698</PO_ID><MAN>HQF01</MAN></SO>"
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml' }
r=requests.post(url, data = payload, headers = headers)
```

Comment: I tried r=requests.post(url,data = payload) but still getting the same error , can u suggest how to use SO in my payload , if you see the xml file posted and the payload I am using, SO is missing .